# Using netbeans, how can I print to the console?

Tags: android, netbeans

I know there are similar questions but none of them include the netbeans ide. any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What 'console' - the netbeans console or some sort of console on the Android device?  The only mechanism to generate logging is the `android.util.Log` class.

Comment: the netbeans console i mean. sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can just use android.util.Log and view the output in the DDMS. Run ddms from the command line, and you'll get a view of the log that you can filter, etc.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a built-in alias in some versions : just type "sout" (+ TAB, it depends i don't remember exactly) and there you go !